# How to view the order of the columns after reordering using Primereact DataTable reorderableColumns property?

Tags: primereact

I am using primereact datatable and the reorderableColumns property to allow reordering of my columns by drag and drop. I am using primereact version 9.1.1. Below is my code. Is there anyway to return the value of the headers of the newly reordered columns?

```
    <DataTable
      reorderableColumns
      value={data}
      header={header}
      tableStyle={{ minWidth: "50rem" }}
    >
      {data}
    </DataTable>
```

[Primereact Datatable docs](https://primereact.org/datatable/#reorder)

Answer (score 1):

I added the onColReorder callback method to  DataTable and it works now.

Here is my new DataTable:

```
    <DataTable
      reorderableColumns
      value={data}
      header={header}
      tableStyle={{ minWidth: "50rem" }}
      onColReorder={onColReorder}
    >
      {data}
    </DataTable>
```

My onColReorder method:

```
  const onColReorder = (event) => {
    // Handle column reorder event
    const reorderedColumns = event.columns.map((column) => column.props.header);
    console.log('Columns reordered:', reorderedColumns );
  };
```

Now, logging reorderedColumns will show the new order of the columns.